# Should Femboys be called El Femboy or La Femboy?

Tags: gramática, género

Simple question. For the word femboy (feminine boy), should we use El, or La in Spanish.

There are two sides of the argument.
One is because only a male can be a femboy, therefore we use El instead of La.
The other is because the word femboy (feminine boy) emits feminine connotation, we should use La instead of El.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**femboy**

---

*Femboy género es una identidad de género no binaria basada en ser un femboy y sus estéticas asociadas, por lo que entra en la categoría de estetigénero. Es un género similar a hombre, pero que cuya presentación se define mejor por elementos femeninos.*

---

Como idea general, en España tenemos presente la enfermedad del Covid. En un principio se utilizó el articulo "el" masculino para designarlo, así decíamos, **"El Covid"**, más tarde, se hizo una interpretación distinta para ser renombrado con el artículo femenino, y así decíamos, "**La Covid**". La conclusión a la que se llegó fue que "**El Covid**" hacia referencia al virus (El virus Covid) y "La Covid" a la enfermedad (La enfermedad Covid).

Aplicado a este caso al término, "**femboy**", y mientras que la persona que se considera "**femboy**", no especifique sus preferencias o lo contrario, dependerá entonces del observador.

Así pues, si el observador considera, particularmente, que la persona "femboy" tiene más rasgos femeninos que masculinos podrá decir "La femboy", si el observador considera que tiene más rasgos masculinos que femeninos el nombre utilizado entonces sería "El femboy".

Si la persona que recibe esa denominación no esta cómoda con el apelativo, el observador por educación cambia el articulo de "**El a La**" o de "**La a EL**" / "**La femboy / El femboy**".

Por otro lado si consideramos desde el punto de vista de "**La persona**", como aspecto indistinto y genérico, siempre será, "**La femboy**" (La persona, dentro de la cual se encuentra el masculino, femenino...), aunque de todas formas, también habrán personas que prefieran que se refieran a ellos con el articulo "El", "El femboy".

---

As a general idea, in Spain we have the Covid disease in mind. At first, the masculine article "el" was used to designate it, so we said, **"El Covid"**, later, a different interpretation was made to be renamed with the feminine article, and so we said, "**La Covid**". The conclusion reached was that "**The Covid**" referred to the virus (The Covid virus) and "La Covid" to the disease (The Covid disease).

Applied in this case to the term, "** femboy **", and while the person who is considered "** femboy **", does not specify her preferences or the opposite, it will then depend on the observer.

Thus, **if the observer** considers, in particular, that the "**femboy**" person has more feminine than masculine traits, they can say **"La femboy"**, **if the observer** considers that they have more masculine than feminine traits, the name used would then be **"El femboy"**.

If the person who receives that denomination is not comfortable with the appellation, the observer for education changes the article from "**El to La**" or from "**La to EL**" / "**La femboy / El femboy**".

On the other hand, if we consider from the point of view of "**The person**" (La persona), as an indistinct and generic aspect, it will always be, "**La femboy**" (La persona, within which is the masculine, feminine...), although in any case, there will also be people who prefer to be referred to with the article "El", "**El femboy**".